# Getting a SIGABERT message when trying to add a video in Xcode 4.5

Tags: xcode4.5

Just to first say that I'm a total coding noob and so I'm probably trying to do something above my knowledge level.  I went online and sought code for adding a video to an x-code program.  I tried various different online tutorials and none of them worked. 
I tried at first to program it into Xcode 4.2 but to no avail.  I then downloaded the latest version 4.5

The build succeeds in the iphone6 simulator but then it fails to actually run.

The error message I'm getting is a SIGABERT:-  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

My header file is:-

```
#import UIkit/UIkit.h (with the smaller than larger than symbols)

#import MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h (with the smaller than larger than symbols)

@interface ViewController :UIViewController {

}

-(IBAction)playvideo;

@end
```

My implementation file is:-

```
#import "ViewController".h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@implementation ViewController


-(IBAction)playvideo {
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
              [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"jamcookvid1" ofType:@"mv4"]];

 MPMoviePlayerViewController *playercontroller =
 [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

[[self navigationController]presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:
 playercontroller];
playercontroller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

[playercontroller.moviePlayer play];
// [playercontroller release];
playercontroller = nil;

}

@end
```

If any of you guys could help me - it would be much appreciated. JB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that your file doesn't exist in the app bundle...or not with that exact spelling.  Try logging the result of `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"jamcookvid1" ofType:@"mv4"]`.  You will probably find it's `nil`, which would explain the message.